# Am I legally obligated to get a driver's license after moving?

Tags: united-states, driving, washington, arizona

I recently moved from Arizona to Washington, and I had to get a Washington Driver's License to be able to register my car (the AZ registration was about to expire).  However, pretending I didn't need to do that, do I legally have to register to drive in the new state?  I would have preferred to keep my Arizona license, which didn't expire until 2051 (AZ licenses don't expire until you turn 65, if you weren't aware).  I'm fully aware that you have to update your voter information, but I'm specifically wondering about the Driver's License.

Comment: Not really... It's a hypothetical that doesn't even apply to me, and I'm asking if I would be legally obligated to do something if I were in a different situation.

Comment: I suspect that the state laws on this are going to vary, so adding tags for Washington and Arizona might be useful. Another factor might might come into play is each state's definition for what permanent resident or primary residence is.

Comment: 2051?!  You might have as well renewed your car for 5 years in Arizona as well!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [Washington State Department of Licensing](http://www.dol.wa.gov/driverslicense/moving.html) website, you have 30 days to get your Washington State drivers license from the time you establish residency in Washington.  You are considered to have established residency if you do any of the following:

- Register to vote
- Receive state benefits
- Get any WA state license at resident rates
- Receive in-state tuition fees

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146272/discussion-on-answer-by-mark-am-i-legally-obligated-to-get-a-drivers-license-af); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.